# The Converse of the Pythagoras Theorem

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle in the plane. Suppose that $AB^2+AC^2=BC^2.$ Prove that:

$\angle BAC$ is right angle.

Remark: I believe this to be true. Now I have the following difficulty. I'm looking for a proof which a 10th grade student can understand, but any effort of mine is via proof by contradiction. I mean assuming that the given angle is not a right angle and then arrive on a contradiction. So I'm looking for a solution which could avoid the indirect method but if not then a solution by the indirect method.

Comment: We habe $AB^2 + AC^2 = BC^2 + 2AB\cdot BC \cdot \cos(\angle ABC)$

Comment: What about Euclid's proof? It's Proposition 48 in first book, you can find the whole book for free here: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/euclid.html

Comment: This can be quickly and easily be proved using the law of cosines, yet a 10th grader perhaps hasn't studied that much trigonometry...

Comment: You can use any proof you like of the cosine formula

Comment: http://europa.sim.ucm.es/compludoc/AA?a=Casey%2c+Stephen&donde=otras&zfr=0

Comment: What is that link, @JpMcCarthy ? Either it malfunctions or else...well, it looks weird.

Comment: @DonAntonio It is a proof of the converse without using Pythagoras Theorem itself. My classmate in college did it and the link is to the Mathematical Gazette citation.

Comment: @DonAntonio Casey, Stephen; Mathematical Gazette; 2008; 92 (524); 309-312; 00255572.

Comment: Still don't get it, @JpMcCarthy : how can that paper be reached?!

Comment: @DonAntonio I think you'll need a hard copy. I am not being as helpful as I had intended!

Comment: Oh, so the paper doesn't exist in PDF form in that site (or any other)?

Comment: @DonAntonio I might email my friend...

Comment: That'd be nice, @JpMcCarthy. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio He doesn't have it anymore. I will go into the Maths department in UCC and scan it (in a month or two --- I haven't forgotten you!)

Comment: Thanks for that, @JpMcCarthy : I appreciate that.

Comment: @DonAntonio The plot thickens. I went into the Maths department, into the room where I definitely saw the issue of the Mathematical Gazette which housed the proof... that one issue is missing! I will email one of the professors who I know helped submit the proof: I am not sure how often he checks his email so I will write to him in two weeks if he hasn't replied. Regards.

Comment: Thanks @JpMcCarthy...and watch that butler!

Comment: Finally!! This is the best I can do: http://jpmccarthymaths.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/pythagoras-converse0001.pdf

Comment: @DonAntonio Steve was an excellent student: top of our class. Sadly  he was lost to physics!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draw side by side the given triangle $\;\Delta ABC\;$ and a new triange $\,PQR\;$ as follows:

$$PQ=AB\;,\;\;PR=AC\;,\;\;\angle QPR=90^\circ$$

Now, we're given $\,AB^2+AC^2=BC^2\;$, and Pythagoras theorem also gives $\,PQ^2+PR^2=QR^2\;$ , so

$$BC^2=AB^2+AC^2=PQ^2+PR^2=QR^2\implies BC=QR$$

and we get $\,\Delta ABC\cong\Delta PQR\;$ by $\;S.S.S.\;$

Answer (score 3):

You can use cosine formula as

$BC^2$ = $AB^2 + AC^2 -2.(AB).(AC)cos(A)$

substituting the condition we get $2.(AB).(AC)cos(\angle BAC)=0$

which gives us $\angle$ $BAC =\pi/2$

Answer (score 0):

a^2+b^2= c^2 in triangle ABC, and argue towards contradiction as 
Draw the altitude of the triangle towards one of the sides making angle C, and call the length from vertix C to this intersection x. Then 
x^2+h^2= b^2 and (a-x)^2+h^2= c^2. Playing around with these three equations shows you that x= 0 which is a contradiction

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You may want to see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to correctly format your posts. Also, could you elaborate on your proof to make it complete and easy to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what always worked for me as a tenth grader was to cut a triangle into right triangles:

Construct a point $D$ on $BC$ so that $DA$ is perpendicular to $BC$ so $ADC$ is a right triangle and $AD^2 + DC^2 = AC^2$.

THere are three possibilities.

i) $\angle ABC$ is acute.

Then $D$ is between $B$ and $C$ and $BC = BD + DC$.

Then $AB^2 = BD^2 + AD^2; AC^2 = AD^2 + DC^2; BC^2 = BD^2 + 2BD*DC + DC^2$

And $AB^2 + BC^2 = AD^2 + DC^2 + 2(BD^2+ BD*DC) = AC^2 + 2(BD^2+ BD*DC) > AC^2$

(It helps if you draw a picture and note $AB > AD; BC > BD$ so of course $AB^2 + BC^2 > AD^2 + DC^2 = AC$.  But the calculation tells you exactly how much bigger.)

ii) $\angle ABC$ is obtuse.

Then $B$ is between $D$ and $C$ and $DC = DB + BC$.

Then $AB^2 = BD^2 + AD^2; AC^2 = AD^2 + DC^2; DC^2 = DB^2 + 2DB*BC + BC^2$

And $AB^2 + BC^2 = AD^2 + DC^2 - 2(BD^2+ BD*DC) = AC^2 - 2(BD^2+ BD*DC) < AC^2$

iii) $\angle ABC$ is right.

Then $B=D$ and $C$ and $DC =  BC $.

Then $AB^2 =  AD^2; AC^2 = AD^2 + DC^2=AB^2 + BC^2; BC^2 = DC^2 $

So i) $AB^2 + BC^2 > AC^2 \implies \triangle ABC$ is acute and $AB^2 + BC^2 = AC + 2(BD^2 + BD*DC)$.

ii) $AB^2 + BC^2 < AC^2 \implies \triangle ABC$ is abtuse and $AB^2 + BC^2 = AC - 2(BD^2 + BD*DC)$.

iii) $AB^2 + BC^2 = AC^2 \implies  \triangle ABC$ is right.

.... which gives the tenth grader a hint of the law of cosines to come.

[i.e. $\pm(BD^2 + DB*DC) = AB*BC*\cos \angle ABC$ which is $0$ if $\angle ABC$ is right; positive if obtuse and negative if acute.]

Answer (score -1):

**Understand Converse of Pythagoras Theorem** with a VIDEO explanation. Click on the link to WATCH the VIDEO: [WATCH VIDEO](http://bit.ly/15MaKt7)

**Converse of Pythagoras Theorem**

In a triangle, if the square of one side is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides, then the angle opposite to the first side is a right angle. 
Given : A triangle ABC such that AB square plus BC square equals to AC square. 
To prove : the triangle ABC is right - angled at B. 
Construction: Construct a right - angled triangle PQR, right - angled at Q such that PQ equal to AB and QR equals to BC. 
Prof: Appling the Pythagoras theorem to right - angled triangle PQR we have PQ square plus QR square equals to PR square or AB square plus BC square is equal to PR square since PQ is equal to AB and QR equals to BC by construction. Let this be equation 1 but it is given that AB square plus BC square equals to AC square. 
From equations 1 and 2 we get PR square equals to AC square i.e., PR equals to AC. 
Therefore, by SSS congruence criterion, we get triangle ABC is congruent to triangle PQR so we get angle B equal to angle Q but we know angle Q is equal to 90 degrees by construction. 
Therefore, angle B equals to 90 degrees. 
Hence, triangle ABC is a right triangle, right - angled at B. 
Thus, the theorem is proved.